# How do I reliably get windowDidBecomeMain and windowDidResignMain events?

Tags: cocoa, swift3, xcode8

I have a view controller in which I want to receive windowDidBecomeMain and windowDidResignMain events.

In viewWillApear() I set the window delegate to self.

```
view.window?.delegate = self
```

I have added an extension to my view controller that conforms to NSWindowDelegate and have implemented both methods in it thus:

```
extension CustomerListViewController: NSWindowDelegate
{
  func windowDidBecomeMain(_ notification: Notification)
  {
    print("Customer list did become main")
  }

  func windowDidResignMain(_ notification: Notification)
  {
    print("Customer list did resign main")
  }
}
```

This is not the initial window. It is opened via a menu item with a Window controller show segue.

When the window is first opened via the menu item, it does not receive windowDidBecomeMain.

When I click another window it *does* receive windowDidResignMain.

If I then click back into the newly opened window it does receive windowDidBecomeMain and will from that point on.

I suspect that I need to set my window delegate at a different point but don't have a clue where to do so, if that *is* the case.